# can't find managed object model?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I created a entity called photo inmy .xcdatamodel.

but when I tried to add it into my context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
Photo *p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

it had run-time error:

> +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name
>   'Photo'

it's really weird, I included the Photo.h, generated by xcode coredata.

does anyone have an idea why it goes wrong?

I can't find what's wrong at all.. > <

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your call to `[self managedObjectContext]` is returning a valid context (and not nil). Also make sure you're using the proper case (you said your entity was called "photo" but you're trying to insert a new object for an entity named "Photo").

Comment: Thank you so much! The context is nil.. Q Q
I really forget to check this!

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Buy it chocolate. Tell it you love it. :-)